# mongodb python , quick pipeline code check

Tags: python, mongodb

i am a beginner to mongodb and i have the assignment to write pipeline code. MY goal is to find the Region in India has the largest number of cities with longitude between 75 and 80? I hope anybody can help me to point out my misconceptions and/or mistakes, it is a very short code, so i am sure the pros will spot it right away.

Here is my code, i will post how the datastructure looks like under it :

```
    pipeline = [
    {"$match" :  {"lon": {"$gte":75, "$lte" : 80}},
                 {'country' : 'India'}},
    { '$unwind' : '$isPartOf'},
    { "$group":
    {
                "_id": "$name",
                "count" :{"$sum":{"cityname":"$name"}} }},

    {"$sort": {"count": -1}},
     {"$limit": 1}

]


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fe1d364b5ab856eea75ebc"),
    "elevation" : 1855,
    "name" : "Kud",
    "country" : "India",
    "lon" : 75.28,
    "lat" : 33.08,
    "isPartOf" : [
        "Jammu and Kashmir",
        "Udhampur district"
    ],
    "timeZone" : [
        "Indian Standard Time"
    ],
    "population" : 1140
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pipeline will give you the desired result. The first [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) pipeline operator uses standard MongoDB queries to filter the documents (cities) whose longitude is between 75 and 80 and as well as the ones only in India based on the `country` field. Since each document represents a city, the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator on the `isPartOf` deconstructs that array field from the filtered documents to output a document for each element. Each output document replaces the array with an element value. Thus for each input document, outputs `n` documents where `n` is the number of array elements and this operation is rather useful in the next [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator stage since that's where you can calculate the number `n` through [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) group accumulator operator. The next pipeline stages will then transform your final document structure by introducing new replacement fields `Region` and `NumberOfCities` + sorting the documents in descending order and then returning the top 1 document which is your region with the largest number of cities:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "lon": {"$gte": 75, "$lte": 80},
            "country": "India"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$isPartOf"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id":  "$isPartOf",
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "Region": "$_id",
            "NumberOfCities": "$count"
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {"NumberOfCities": -1}
    },
    { "$limit": 1 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax and logical errors in your pipeline.

1. > {"$match" :  {"lon": {"$gte":75, "$lte" : 80}},
   >                {'country' : 'India'}},

The Syntax here is wrong, you should just use comma to seperate key value pairs in `$match.

2. > "_id": "$name",

You are grouping based on city name and not on the region.

3. > {"$sum":{"cityname":"$name"}}

You need to send a numeric values to the [`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#sum-aggregation) operator that result from applying a specified expression. `{"cityname":"$name"}` will be ignored.

The correct pipeline would be :-

```
[
    {"$match" :  {"lon": {"$gte":75,"$lte" : 80},'country' : 'India'}},
    { '$unwind' : '$isPartOf'},
    { "$group":
        {
                "_id": "$isPartOf",
                "count" :{"$sum":1}
         }
    },
    {"$sort": {"count": -1}},
    {"$limit": 1}

]
```

If you want to get all the cities in that region satisfying your condition as well ,you can add `"cities": {'$push': '$name'}` in the **`$group`** stage.